# Magento : Setting Shipping Origin Dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address

My website have multiple origin shipping address and I want it to pick origin address according to my customer address. I have way to pick origin shipping address according to customer address but my origin address is not working. I have found code for setting config of store but its not working for me as my store is picking up address and postal code provided in admin of magento...

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$configScope = array(
'street_line1' => $street1,
'street_line2' => $street2,
'city'         => $city,
'region_id'    => $region_id,
'postcode'     => $postcode,
'country_id'   => $country_id
);

foreach($configScope as $_scope=>$_val){
$store->setConfig('shipping/origin/' . $_scope, $_val);
}
```